# macOS window minimization time modifying

Tags: macos, window, dock

I have a problem finding the file where the time for minimizing a window is written.

I modified the time for my dock to disappear with the command to make the dock hide and come up in 0 time, so basically instantly.

`defaults write com.apple.dock autohide-time-modifier -int 0`

now i want to do the same with the minimizing effect (no matter whether the genie or scale effect), but i couldn't find the file containing it.

so basically I am looking for something like `com.apple.whatever minimizing-time-modifier -int 0`